# Better way to add style to a single nested list item in kramdown

Tags: html, css, kramdown

I'm using kramdown, and would like a concise way to add a style the beginning of an `li` element, without applying that style to any list nested in that item.  For example

```
* I want style here
  * but not here
  * or here
```

The code below does what I want; but, I'd like to avoid having to explicitly add the `span` tags, if possible.

```
* <span>I want style here</style>{: .my-class}
   * but not here 
   * or here
```

I like the look/feel of the approach below; but, as expected, it applies the styling to the entire list item (which includes the nested list).

```
   * {: .my-class} I want style here
     * but not here
     * or here
```

Is there either
  1. A kramdown trick to concisely define an arbitrary `span` (similar to `*some text here*{: .my-class}`, but without the default styling that comes with `*`, `_`, and backticks?, or
  2. A CSS trick that would apply styling to only the portion of an `li` tag outside any nested `ul` or `ol`?

Comment: I feel like there should be a way to do this with the `:not()` psuedo element. I tried `.li:not(li ul li){ ... }` but this doesn't work. There might be a way to make this work tho.

Comment: Your option 1. is not available with kramdown.